# How can I change the X and Y coordinates of a sprite?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a pong game replica just to have fun.

I'm trying so that if the ball touches a sprite (called the enemy sprite), the ball will move to the center of the screen but I don't know how to do that with pygame.

```
#sprites
speed = [10,10]
bola = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
bola = pygame.transform.scale(bola, (27,27))
ballrect = bola.get_rect()
player1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (x, y, width, height))
player2 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (650, y2, width, height))
enemy = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (0, 0, 3, winheight,))
ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)

#center of screen
centerX = winwidth/2
centerY = winheight/2

#collision with left wall (called enemy sprite)
if ballrect.colliderect(enemy):
  puntos = puntos + 1
  print(puntos)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it.

```
speed = [10,10]
bola = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
bola = pygame.transform.scale(bola, (27,27))
ballrect = bola.get_rect()
ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)

#change x and y of the ball

centerX = winwidth/2
centerY = winheight/2
ballrect.y = centerY
ballrect.x = centerX
```

So basically to change and get the x and y position of a sprite in pygame, you have to add '.x' or '.y' after the name of the sprite rect.